# Apache2 reverse proxy multiple sources into one http connection

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, raspberry-pi2, http-proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy on my Apache2 web server. It's not really pertinent to the question, but I have a Raspberry Pi running a music player with an HTTP interface attached to an unrestricted internet connection. I want to be able to control the music from a work machine which is behind a content filter that blocks Spotify.

Client ---> Content Filter ----> My proxy ---> Unblocked target server

                                                       |

                                                       |

                                                      /

                                            Blocked content

I want clients to be able to connect to my proxy server and view the pages on my unblocked target server. I am currently able to do this using the following code in my `VirtualHost` section:

```
<Location "/foo">
    ProxyPass "http://targetserver/bar"
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

This allows me to see the page when I visit `http://myproxy/foo` but it doesn't load completely. I know that this is from content that is being blocked by a content filter that I cannot influence.

How do I configure my Apache2 proxy server to also forward the content that the client would normally receive from external servers? I want my proxy server to provide all the content to the client for this web interface opaquely.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I needed to proxy the websockets as well. Adding the following lines worked:

```
ProxyPass /foo/ ws://targetserver/bar/
ProxyPassReverse /foo/ ws://targetserver/bar/
```